# date time showing month value zero

Tags: c#, datetime, date

hi I am using mysql as a database it will accept date format like this (yyyy-mm-dd) when the user enter  in the text box in any format it will accept only format listed above. I have tried this one by using below code

```
string dob = tbDob.Text;
DateTime dv = DateTime.Parse(dob);
string format = dv.ToString("yyyy-mm-dd");
```

but it will showing the month as zero

input :19-08-1908

output:1908-00-19

would any one solve this pls...

Comment: I've retagged this as C#, since neither sql nor mysql are relevant here, and the syntax and API names look an awful lot like C#. Please correct that tag if I've interpreted wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are formatting the string according to "yyyy-mm-dd". But you are giving input in the format

input :19-08-1908

so it taking year as 1908, ie its combining 19 and 08 and its taking month as 00 and date as 19 (19 out of 1908).

Change the input format to yyyy-mm-dd, instead, to get the correct output.

Comment: This should be unmarked as it's not the right answer. @VoteyDisciple's solution is correct.

Answer (score 12):

`mm` is for minutes; `MM` is for month.

Try `dv.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")`

If that's not the format you had in mind, try:

- `M`: Numeric month (no leading zero)
- `MM`: Numeric month (with leading zero)
- `MMM`: Abbreviated month name (e.g., "Jan")
- `MMMM`: Full month name (e.g., "January")

Comment: `m is fo Numeric representation of a month, with leading zeros` and `i is for Minutes with leading zeros` amd `M is for short textual representation of a month, three letters` - http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Comment: @NAVEED You're looking at the PHP manual. Although the question is not tagged one way or the other, we can see from the syntax alone this clearly is not PHP.